# Non-zero maps between modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $M,N$ two $R$-modules such that there exists a **non-zero** map $\psi : M \to N$. Is it true that there exists a non-zero map $\varphi: N \to M$  ?

I do not have any particular restriction on $R$. Thanks for any comment and remark!

Answer (score 4):

Consider $R=\mathbb Z$, $M=\mathbb Z$ and $N=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Please oh please oh please oh please try to look for examples of things.

Comment: But she _did_ look for an example! Found one, too, right here...

Comment: Right, apology for this question, I tried to think about difficult cases to find a (counter)example, and I am not a fan of module theory. Last thing: what about if we request that $N$ is projective (and R commutative, say)?